# Windows phone dot and comma

Tags: replace, windows-phone-8

what is the best way to replace a comma with a dot in a float, without messing with the culture / locale files - because parts of my app depend on its current setting.

Is there maybe a .Replace() method or something?

`txtAirtime.Text = "R" + new_val; (new_val at this time is 1.61)`

Comment: A float doesn't have either a dot or a comma in it. It's just binary until you apply a locale. What's your scenario (e.g. are you converting from a string to a float type and back to a string)- and can you show some code?

Comment: I have something weird, I get a float which displays a 1.61, then I concat a "R" to it and it becomes 1,61

Comment: That doesn't make sense outside of the context of your code. Neither float or string have a concat method.

Comment: txtAirtime.Text = "R" + new_val; (new_val at this time is 1.61), once I "plus" the "R" symbol, the text displaying in txtAirtime.text is "1,61" instead of "1.61"

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is doing an automatic float-to-string conversion, using the current locale of the emulator / phone.

You will need to do an explicit float-to-string conversion that tells the compiler not to take into account the current locale.

`txtAirtime.Text = "R" + new_val.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`